# How can I convert a string to a stream?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream, datacontractserializer

I would like to parse some JSON:

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(STMsgObj));
            STMsgObj[] messages = (STMsgObj[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);

            foreach(STMsgObj aMsg in messages){
                MessageBox.Show(aMsg.body, "Data Passed", MessageBoxButton.OK); 
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I convert e.Result into a stream?

Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=InvalidCastException
  StackTrace:
       at StockTwits.ViewModels.StreamPage.webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
       at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result)))
{
    // Your code here, using stream.
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code with your snippet. I am getting an InvalidCastException on readObject.

Comment: This is an entirely different question. The result of the deserialize is not a `STMsgObj[]`. I do not know how to fix this. Since your original question has been answered, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Call `DownloadDataAsync` instead.

You can then pass `new MemoryStream(e.Result)` from the `DownloadDataCompleted` event.

If you really want to stick with `DownloadStringAsync`, you can pass `XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(e.Result))`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that WebClient wraps an API that is already stream based means there are a number of unnecessary conversions. You might want to consider swapping your `WebClient` for plain old `HttpWebRequest`, which hands you a stream out of the box.

```
HttpWebRequest req=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
using(var resp=req.GetResponse())
using(var stream=resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data isn't an array.